# AngularJS form - ng-model becoming undefined after typing in input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've done this a million times before so im slightly confused what is going on here.

I have a form called placementForm with numerous fields but whenever i type in any of them other than candidateName, the field goes to undefined but if i remove the text then it goes back to "".

I have a form using these fields(controller aswell)

```
var application = angular.module('timeSheetsApplication',[]);

application.controller("portalController",
    function($scope) {
        $scope.placementForm = {};
        $scope.placementForm.candidateName = "";
        $scope.placementForm.clientName = "";
        $scope.placementForm.jobTitle = "";
        $scope.placementForm.placementStartDate = "";
        $scope.placementForm.placementEndDate = "";
        $scope.placementForm.frequency = "";
    });
```

and the form being:

```
    <div class="md-form">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix red-text"></i>
        <input type="email" id="clientName" class="form-control" ng-model="placementForm.clientName" placeholder="Client Name">
    </div>


    <div class="md-form">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix red-text"></i>
        <input type="email" id="txtJobTitle" class="form-control" ng-model="placementForm.jobTitle"placeholder="Job Title">
    </div>

    <div class="md-form">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix red-text"></i>
        <input type="email" id="placementStartDate" class="form-control datepicker" ng-model="placementForm.placementStartDate" placeholder="Placement Start Date">
    </div>


    <div class="md-form">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix red-text"></i>
        <input type="email" id="placementEndDate" class="form-control datepicker"  ng-model="placementForm.placementEndDate" placeholder="Placement End Date">
    </div>

    <select class="mdb-select" ng-model="placementForm.frequency">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="WEEK">Weekly</option>
        <option value="MONTH">Monthly</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: My bad, its due to the inputs being the incorrect type.

Comment: too slow, but yeah, you need `type="text"`, etc.